# Implementing Anonymous User Checkout Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build an e-commerce website. I have created different apps.

1. accounts
2. carts
3. orders
4. products

I want to implement the anonymous user checkout that if the user is not logged in, he is redirected to Guest User Checkout Form. I have tried removing the login_required decorator but I have not been successful modifying it.Currently, my orders app models look like this. I

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from accounts.models import UserAddress
# Create your models here.

from carts.models import Cart

STATUS_CHOICES =(
        ("Started", "Started"),
        ("Abandoned", "Abandoned"),
        ("Finished", "Finished"),

    )

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='ABC', unique=True)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="Started")
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(UserAddress, related_name='shipping_address', default=1)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(UserAddress, related_name='billing_address',default=1)
    sub_total = models.DecimalField(default=10.99, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    tax_total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    final_total = models.DecimalField(default=10.99, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)


    # address **

    status = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="Started")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.order_id
```

and the view looks like this

```
import time

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.

from accounts.forms import UserAddressForm
from accounts.models import UserAddress
from carts.models import Cart

from .models import Order
from .utils import id_generator

def orders(request):
    context = {}
    template = "orders/user.html"
    return render(request, template, context)


#require user login ** 
@login_required
def checkout(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        the_id = None
        #return HttpResponseRedirect("/cart/")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))

    try:
        new_order = Order.objects.get(cart=cart)
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        new_order = Order()
        new_order.cart = cart
        print new_order.cart
        new_order.user = request.user
        new_order.order_id = id_generator()
        new_order.save()
    except:
        new_order = None
        # work on some error message
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
    if new_order is not None:
        new_order.sub_total = cart.total
        new_order.save()

    try:
        address_added = request.GET.get("address_added")
    except:
        address_added = None

    if address_added is None:
        address_form = UserAddressForm()
    else:
        address_form = None

    current_addresses = UserAddress.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    billing_addresses = UserAddress.objects.get_billing_addresses(user=request.user)
    print billing_addresses
    ##1 add shipping address
    ##2 add billing address
    #3 add and run credit card 
    if new_order.status == "Finished":
        #cart.delete()
        del request.session['cart_id']
        del request.session['items_total']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))

    context = {
    "order":new_order,
    "address_form": address_form,
    "current_addresses": current_addresses,
    "billing_addresses": billing_addresses,
    }
    template = "orders/checkout.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

My cart app models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from products.models import Product, Variation

class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    variations = models.ManyToManyField(Variation, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    line_total = models.DecimalField(default=10.99, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null =True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        try:
            return str(self.cart.id)
        except:
            return self.product.title


class Cart(models.Model):
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Cart id: %s" %(self.id)
```

and the Cart view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your views here.

from products.models import Product, Variation

from .models import Cart, CartItem

def view(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        the_id = None
    if the_id:

        new_total = 0.00
        for item in cart.cartitem_set.all():
            line_total = float(item.product.price) * item.quantity
            new_total += line_total

        request.session['items_total'] = cart.cartitem_set.count()
        cart.total = new_total
        cart.save()
        context = {"cart": cart}
    else:
        empty_message = "Your Cart is Empty, please keep shopping."
        context = {"empty": True, "empty_message": empty_message}

    template = "cart/view.html"
    return render(request, template, context)

def remove_from_cart(request, id):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))

    cartitem = CartItem.objects.get(id=id)
    # cartitem.delete()
    cartitem.cart = None
    cartitem.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))



def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    request.session.set_expiry(120000)

    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        new_cart = Cart()
        new_cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
        the_id = new_cart.id

    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass

    product_var = [] #product variation
    if request.method == "POST":
        qty = request.POST['qty']

        for item in request.POST:
            key = item
            val = request.POST[key]
            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(product=product, category__iexact=key, title__iexact=val)
                product_var.append(v)
            except:
                pass
        cart_item= CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart, product=product)      
        if len(product_var) > 0:
            cart_item.variations.add(*product_var)
        cart_item.quantity = qty
        cart_item.save()


        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

PS: I am beginner trying to learn django.

Comment: What exactly do you want to ask?

Comment: handling the anonymous user request for the checkout and not using the login_required decorator

Comment: But you don't need to use ```@login_required```. It's used *only* when you have to limit access to some view to registered and authenticated users, which is not your case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an e-commerce framework like [django-oscar](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/)?

As for the `@login_required`, you could add a [login_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) parameter to redirect to your anonymous checkout URL. I.e.:

```
@login_required(login_url='/checkout/new-user')
```

and connect the /checkout/new-user URL to your anonymous checkout view in the `urls.py` module.

Comment: No I have not. I have all the other functionalities working except this one so I was just thinking to modify this instead using django-oscar

Comment: The reason I needed to mention frameworks is that the DIY approach will add a lot of functional and security testing.

Comment: Thank you for that . I will surely be checking it out .